# Email a lead on adding as a campaign member

Tags: email-template, leads, campaign, campaign-member

I've created a registration form via a public site where a lead is created and immediately added to a campaign via a visualforce page and custom controller (not web to lead).

The coding is the easy part (apparently).  How can I send an email template to that lead?  I'm trying process builder and workflow but I can't send an email template only an email alert.  Perhaps email alert will work but I can't figure out how to send that to a newly created lead.

Use Case:  user enters email clicks submit (complete) -> lead is created and added to campaign members object (complete) -> [now on create of that campaign members record] I want to send the email template to the lead: "thanks for registering..." (need to complete)

Currently I have an email alert set up but it's not emailing the lead

```
Workflow rule:
Object: Campaign Member
Rule Criteria: Campaign: Campaign Name EQUALS AMCC - Mobility Session
Evaluation Criteria:    Evaluate the rule when a record is created


Email Alert
Object: Campaign Member
Recipients  Email Field: Email
```

I suspect the problem is the recipient field becuase this is a public site.

Comment: is your requirement to not use code at all? Or doing so via code's fine?

Comment: I'd prefer not to do code but given my deadline I'll use it for now.

Comment: don't understand what problem you have - you could use email template in email alerts in workflows.

Comment: It's not emailing the lead.  I added some more detail in the question

Comment: What you're actually doing is performing is a task that's related to the Campaign. You're going to want it show up as a related activity on that Campaign when the New Campaign Member is created. This workflow should be firing on the Campaign which acts on it's child Campaign Member.

Comment: so do I modify the email alert or the workflow?

Comment: Campaign member worked.  I didn't initialize All Email in my sandbox?!?!

Answer (score 1):

Email alert off the Campaign Member worked.  The problem was my organization email policy in my SANDBOX.